# Migrate from 2.* to 3.* value map interpreted as text edit widget

Tags: qgis, qml

After switching to QGIS 3.* from 2.* some of my layers style forms are not working anymore. Fields that previously had value map applied to them is now showing as text edit.

Is there a way of transferring them in an easy way?

I tried saving the style both in PostGIS and as QML but non of the option retained the form style.

[image: Value map is not applied when moving from QGIS 2.* to 3.*]

Value map is not applied when moving from QGIS 2.* to 3.*
[image]

After taking a look in the xml the structure is different. Is there a way around this or do i have to recreate my style form i qgis 3.*?

Comment: I think we need some more details on the broken styles.

Comment: In what form are you looking for? I can generate a mockup QML file as comparison. Is QML interpreted differently in 2 vs 3?

Comment: Maybe start with explaining what you did in 2.x based on what attributes and then show comparing images from 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: Not sure there is much more to explain than what the image above describe. I saved my layer style including form style with applied value map as above in a QML file. If i load the QML file to the same layer in Q3 it is not parsed the same way and so for the same field it displays as text edit and not as the specified value map

Comment: Nobody but you has an idea how your map should look like, and how it does instead. So please add according screenshots.

Comment: I am not speaking of style for map canvas layers but Attribute form